# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException while deploying on jboss

Tags: xmlbeans

I have a weird problem that will make me crazy since 3 days.
I'm generating a client stub(xmlbeans) using  axis from a wsdl file then using it to call Ms CRM web service.
My webservice call is working fine in eclipse (having added generated xml resources to classpath) and when i export everything to my jboss server I'm getting this error:
the cause is 'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException' 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException

XMLStreamException  is within the xmlbeans-2.3.jar file which is included within the dependencies in the server side so I can't understand why it stops working when deployed to jboss.

JDKs version are exactly the same as well as lib jars.

Any ideas please.

Thankss

Comment: Can you list you JBoss classpath libs, and your application libs?
`NoClassDefFoundError` means it cannot be found, not that it is not included. In many cases, having 2 or more versions of a `.jar` can lead to this error. Make sure your JBoss doesn't already have the `jar` in its classpath and that you are not dding a duplicate of it (possibly a different version too)

Comment: you're probably accidentally running your application server on lower version of Java

Answer (score 0):

Applies to versions <= 3.17 (Java 6):

This error indicates that the class XMLEventFactory does not provide functionality which POI is depending upon. There can be a number of different reasons for this:

Outdated xml-apis.jar, stax-apis.jar or xercesImpl.jar:
These libraries were required with Java 5 and lower, but are not actually required with spec-compliant Java 6 implementations, so try removing those libraries from your classpath. If this is not possible, try upgrading to a newer version of those jar files.
Running IBM Java 6 (potentially as part of WebSphere Application Server):
IBM Java 6 does not provide all the interfaces required by the XML standards, only IBM Java 7 seems to provide the correct interfaces, so try upgrading your JDK.